# Kotlin generics abstract class

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I have an abstract class in Kotlin:

```
abstract class SimpleRecyclerAdapter<VH : SimpleRecyclerAdapter.Holder, D> constructor(
     context: Context, 
     var data: MutableList<D>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {

    //inner class inside main
    abstract class Holder constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {}
}
```

Everything work fine, but my inner class `Holder` does not see a `D` parameter of the `outer` class and `data` variable

If i mark `Holder` class as `inner` class like that:

```
abstract inner class Holder constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {}
```

D parameter is visible for now, but here

```
SimpleRecyclerAdapter<VH : SimpleRecyclerAdapter.Holder, D>
```

im getting an error `"2 type arguments expected for class..."` 
and here `RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>` `"expected RecyclerView.ViewHolder, found VH"` - seems like `VH` is not visible.
Where am i wrong? I need a `D` parameter inside an `inner` class, but with inner keyword its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the error that you encounter when you add the `inner` modifier, you need to specify the type arguments for the outer class at the inner class' use sites:

```
abstract class SimpleRecyclerAdapter<VH : SimpleRecyclerAdapter<VH, D>.Holder, D> 
                                                               ^^^^^^^
```

And the complete code:

```
abstract class SimpleRecyclerAdapter<VH : SimpleRecyclerAdapter<VH, D>.Holder, D> (
    context: Context,
    var data: MutableList<D>
): RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {

    //inner class inside main
    abstract inner class Holder constructor(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        fun foo(d: D) = Unit // D is visible here
    }
}
```